# Given a set of nonnegative numbers, put $\pm$ between them to minimize the magnitude of the result

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, arithmetic, discrete-optimization

Let's say I have a finite set of non-negative numbers.

I have to put $+$ or $-$ between the numbers, in order to minimize the absolute sum.(i.e the sum has to be closest to 0)

For example:
the set: $8$, $4.5$, $1$, $4$, then 
the solution: $-8 + 4.5 -1 +4$, which gives absolute sum of $0.5$ - which is the smallest possible.

No doubt, that it can be done by checking all the options which is $2^n$ - my question whether there is more efficient way of solving the case.

Comment: This is basically the [Partition Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem)

Comment: @ JimmyK4542 Thank you. I'll read more about it.